# Sed grabbing tags & newlines (Mac OSX)

Tags: regex, sed

I have this text where I need to remove the page numbers:

```
<p class="p3">El gabinete se iba iluminando lentamente ... Por delante de las</p>
<p class="p5"><span class="s4"><i>32</i></span> grandes nubes de un color violeta obscuro...</p>
<p class="p3">
```

I need to remove

```
</p>
<p class="p5"><span class="s4"><i>32</i></span>
```

from it.

So far I have this

```
sed -E -i '' 's/</p>\n<p class="p[0-9]+"[^>]*><span class=".+">.+<\/span> / /g' Capítulo1.html
```

But that is not working it works without the `</p>\n` part, but I really need to capture and replace the `</p>` too.

Note this is on Mac and sed seems to be a bit different from Linux.
Also the  paragraph classes can be anything starting with p followed by a number,similar for the span class s followed by number, and the italic tags can be there or not and in between is the pagenumber.

Comment: doing this with sed is abit risky, you don't know somewhere there are linebreaks or spaces... they are valid in html...

Comment: It's pretty consistent like the example above even if there are spaces or other linebreaks everything from </p> till the ens </span> tag has to be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the newlines really matter, you could try stripping them out first:

```
tr -d '\n' | sed ...
```

Comment: I don't need all newlines to disappear just the one in front

Comment: @Stofke But removing all of them might make it simpler to use sed on the text. Would removing newlines do any harm?

Answer (score 0):

You missed escaping the forwardslash of the closing paragraph tag, try this:

`'s/<\/p>\r?\n<p class="p\d+"[^>]*><span class=".+">.+<\/span> / /g' Capítulo1.html`

For a more complete match as you've described, try this:

`'s/<\/p>\r?\n<p class="p\d+"[^>]*?><span class="s\d+">(<i>)?\d+(<\/i>)?<\/span>/ /g' Capítulo1.html`

This more specifically narrows down the span class matching, and adds non-greediness to stop any unexpected surprises when a huge chunk of data is removed between a span opening tag and the furthest matching span closing tag.

Comment: I think you are pretty close with that regex I know I made rough regex but only because sed seems to be so difficult.  I didn't notice the escape but still it is complaining:

sed: 1: "s/<\/p>\r?\n<p class="p ...": RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Comment: The first one gives no error but also doesn't replace it while if I use the same regex in sublime text for example it captures the right part

Comment: by the way sed doesn't support non-greedy matches